# can sqlite3_open API open connection to multiple database files over a single instance?

Tags: database, sqlite, database-connection

I am opening a connection to **config1.sqlit**e file kept at suppose /x/y/config1.sqlite path via **sqlite3_open(const** **void*** **path**, **sqlite3**** **db_ref****)**. It is working fine.

Now, I want one more connection to the same **config1.sqlite** file, being a copy kept at different path say, /x/z/config1.sqlite path.
I am not sure whether sqlite3_open API can open **connections to multiple database files** over same **db_ref** specified above.

please someone tell can it be possible?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

sqlite3_open cannot do this; you always get a new, independent database connection.

However, you can [attach](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) a database to another opened database connection:

```
sqlite3_open("/x/y/config1.sqlite");
sqlite3_execute("ATTACH '/x/z/config1.sqlite' AS z");
sqlite3_execute("SELECT * FROM main.tab");
sqlite3_execute("SELECT * FROM z.tab");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :) I have not tried this yet, will try it.